# Doble ejecución de métodos en Spring

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, controller

soy nuevo en esto y les comento que estoy haciendo un curso de spring framework y me encuentro con un problema que en este momento un impedimento para continuar, pero si no lo resuelvo cuando llegue a la parte de base de datos va a ser un gran problema.

El problema que tengo es que los métodos (algo muy simple, mostrar un simple mensaje en consola) dentro de un controlador, se ejecutan 2 veces. He ejecutado el proyecto con Debug y efectivamente pasa dos veces por el método ejecutado. En este momento como mencioné antes no es un problema que me impida continuar, pero al escribir o consultar en una base de datos voy a tener ejecuciones no deseadas ni controladas y bueno... que es un problema bastante grande si no logro controlarlo desde ahora. Mi servidor es Apache Tomcat V9.0. la version de spring-webmvc es 5.2.3.RELEASE 
Ojala puedan darme una idea de que puede estar pasando para controlar un poco mas. Sin duda algo estoy haciendo mal o algo me falta... 
Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que puedan darme!!

El ejemplo de la imagen es un método que se ejecuta al hacer click en un botón, este metodo recibe un dato. Pero no es el único método que se ejecuta dos veces, todos los métodos siempre son ejecutados 2 veces.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/detail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mostrarDetalle(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int idPelicula){
    System.out.println("idPelicula: " + idPelicula);

    LocalDateTime locaDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    int hours = locaDate.getHour();
    int minutes = locaDate.getMinute();
    int seconds = locaDate.getSecond();
    System.out.println("Hora actual : " + hours + ":"+ minutes +":"+seconds);


    String tituloPelicula = "Rapido y furioso";
    int duracion = 136;
    double precioEntrada = 50;
    model.addAttribute("titulo", tituloPelicula);
    model.addAttribute("duracion", duracion);
    model.addAttribute("precio", precioEntrada);
    return "detalle";
}
```

[image: En la imagen muestro la doble ejecución]

Comment: Es recomendable subir el código crudo, en vez de una imágen, ésta puede ser no bien recibida por la comunidad. Edita tú pregunta y anexa tu código. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo, acabo de añadir el código de la función que estoy ejecutando. La imagen la adjunté mas que nada para mostrar el resultado que estoy obteniendo por consola. El problema que estoy presentando yo creo que no tiene error en el código, creo que puede ser algo de configuración o de servidor. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bueno, comento que el problema mencionado solo es en chrome. He eliminado el navegador y lo he vuelto a instalar y sucede algo curioso, sin mis datos de navegación ni mi cuenta de google sincronizada todo va bien, pero desde que sincronizo mi cuenta vuelvo a tener el error. De la única forma que logro que no falle es si ingreso como "invitado". Si alguien sabe a que se debe agradecería que me ayude. Muchas gracias!